# QT Creater - Deploy to Android Emulator fails - INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: android, qt

Posting a solution that I couldn't find anywhere to save others time.

Fresh install of QT Creator. After setting up the stuff new to deploy to Android as detailed here;

https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-developing-android.html#specifying-android-device-settings

I was able to run the Android examples (Chart for example)

But when I made a new project and tried to deploy to my Android Emulator (on a mac, btw), I got the following error;

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

The fix was to check the x86 and/or x86_64 in the build steps as shown below;

[Build Settings/Build Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW1HT.png)